Video game from the film “Murder Story” (1989)
From movie "Murder story"


is from a console with small joystick

anyone know the title?

Found it! The game is Enduro racer 1986 for Atari ST
The console is not show in the movie  but I found a version of Enduro Racer for Atari ST identical to the version show in movie, the game looks different from coinop only in few parts, probably because the console port was modified (some old videogames when ported to console was a little different from coin-op version)
Some images to compare
From the movie:


From Atari ST version:




From coinop:


curiosity: you will see the racers "long" on movie screenshot and "flatted" in modern screens because old tv use 4:3 and now we are all on 16:9

The road in the movie isn't striped and the status layout is different. I don't think this is a match.

Coin-op version is a little different, I will post Atari ST version soon. When coinop were ported to console or home computers (C64, amiga, etc.) some parts were a little (or more) different

Agreed; for the record: my original comment related to an earlier version of this answer which did not include Atari ST screenshots and which — although it included a heading for Atari ST screenshots within nothing underneath, indicating they'd soon arrive — I nevertheless misread.

Your Atari ST emulator should have an option to display the game in the correct aspect ratio. Most emulators usually default to a "fit screen" setting which stretches everything to avoid having big black vertical lines showing up on 16:9 screens.

Just wanted to point out that it appears the actress is using a joystick controller for the Sega Master System, which had a version of this game, but was quite a different game.

@OpiesDad Photo? To me, that looks like an Atari 7800 stick. I can't remember if 7800 sticks are pin-compatible with the Atari ST though.

@ssokolow Ahhh, I think you’re right; I wasn’t familiar with that controller.
